# how can I have primary key when getting data from users?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm a beginner in programming and data base and I want to a text area in html page and getting data from users(it is easy). I can store the text in a data base column without defining a primary key. Now I want to delete some column and I don't know how can I do that. please help me and tell me what should I define as a primary key if it is necessary. thanks.

Comment: You say you already have this database set-up, can we have the schema for the table you are referring to in the question?

Comment: no it is just on the paper without implementation. please say what should be a primary key?

Comment: Before worrying about the implementation, think about it logically... When you want to delete something, how can you *identify* the thing you want to delete?  (Same thing for when you want to modify something, display something, etc.)  The "primary key" is just an implementation concern.  *How you identify something* is a logical concern that you have to define.

Comment: Ah right, well it depends on the database you are using but usually an auto incremented value is recommended to be a primary key for example: `user_id` which would increase on every record added to the table, making it unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter user table:

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
ADD COLUMN `id`  int NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST ;
```

Then you can using `id` is a unique id for query user

Comment: you say, I should define a field as a primary key with NULL and AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. but how can I access them. for example I want to SELECT all columns in my date base and put a delete button under each one. that when I press the delete button, I DELETE it field.

Comment: when you select user and show in view, you should pass user->id to delete button like <button onclick="delete(<?=user->id?>)"></button>

Comment: thanks. it was useful and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a row you need to know whats unique with that row and use those columns as part of the delete. i.e. if you have a column date and uses as the unique index, you can do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE user='arnold' AND date='2016-02-18';
```

If you have multiple rows that match, all will be deleted.

I do however suggest you create a unique primary key. Will make your life easier. A primary key can very often be a auto number so you have something unique to refer back to the row.

Comment: it's a good idea but if I define date and time as a primary key, how can I implement it in MySQL with PHP?

Comment: A primary key is a SQL thing only. Making it fast to lookup (as it is indexed) and make sure you will hit one row using it (as it is unique). The PHP part just build the query and execute it.

Comment: thanks. it was so useful.